# GWT csrf protection remoteServlet methods still marked as experimental

Tags: gwt, csrf-protection

Gwt Documentation http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideSecurityRpcXsrf.html 
as well as GWT IN action
https://manning-content.s3.amazonaws.com/download/d/07888ea-bada-44cc-9c55-ead15ea7fe85/GWT_sample-07.pdf
recommend extending XsrfProtectedService on client side and XsrfProtectedServiceServlet on server side....

But both thse methods are still marked as 
"EXPERIMENTAL and subject to change. Do not use this in production code. "

What gives? is this a leftover - or are they now safe to use in production?

Thanks for your help in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The file has not changed in 7 years.  Google is very conservative in their code, and will put scary warnings or mark things as beta when they are, in fact, production ready.

That said, in *all* matters of security, you should likely submit your code to professionals for security review.  This example is using a predictable hash of JSESSIONID, so you need to ensure your JSESSIONID is configured correctly.  It *must* have a domain (and should have a path) so it is only readable on your domain, on URLs deemed safe (once again, professional review is good).  If this cookie can be leaked, it becomes trivial for an attacker to exploit.